# "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500" when using Vite

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, vite

I am using Vite for my React project, and I'm trying to connect to my backend server, but I'm constantly getting the error "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500" when I use relative path. I have looked at every possible article that I have found and nothing has solved my problem. It's working as expected when I use an absolute path, but of course that's not really the ideal way to use it (I guess).

This is the code snippet that is not working:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_REQUEST' });
      try {
        const result = await axios.get('/api/songs');
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: result.data });
        console.log(result.data);
      } catch (error) {
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_FAIL', payload: error.message });
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

This is my Vite config:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'https://localhost:3000',
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I also tried to add "rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^/api/, '')," to my proxy in the Vite config, and it didn't work.

Comment: Check payload in network tab in inspect menu in both cases, I am sure something wrong is being passed in payload to backend which will lead to 500 internal server error.

Comment: As far as I know I'm not passing anything to my backend, this only sends a get all request to a mongoDB database, that is working perfectly when using the absolute address. Then again, I'm relatively new to backend programming, so please bare with me if I'm saying something stupid.

Comment: If you're passing GET request to backend than changing absolute path or relative path don't return 500 error on server side, I am pretty sure you're passing something in payload to backend for GET data, Check payload in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

A 500 status code usually means that something went wrong on the server while processing the request, so you need to check the server logs.

You may need use a tool like Postman or cURL to make a direct request to the `/api/songs` endpoint and see if it returns the expected response. This can help you isolate whether the issue is with the frontend or the backend.

Comment: I have been using Postman and when I use the complete adress of the backend it works fine, but when I just add it to the Vite port it gives me the same error. The backend (atleast it seems like it) does it's job well, the problem is (I think) with Vite not redirecting to the proxy.

Comment: @bbarna9 Is your backend configured to use HTTPS or HTTP? Ensure that the target corresponds to the appropriate protocol.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's configured the right way, but as I have mentioned in the above comments, I'm pretty new to backend programming, thus I don't have too much insight on what could be wrong here.